# multiprocessing csv writing writes into the last index of each chunk of rows only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I am trying to have multiple operations a dataframe; one of them is to check the value of one column of it, if it's more than 3, this value is turned into zero. The code I wrote worked fine sequentially and the output was as expected. However, when I tried to paralyze it, using multiprocessing library, the output was not as expected. After some thoughts, I ended up discovering that only the last row of every csv file (chunk) in the `temporary_saved_files2` (before concatenating them and removing the folder as it will be shown in the code) is processed, however all the rows remain zeros. this is the code:

```
df_final=pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(len(df)), columns=df.columns.tolist())
#df_final=pd.DataFrame()
def generate(df_plus_id):
    df = df_plus_id[0]
    df_final =  df_plus_id[1]
    ## my operationsss and processing

   if df_plus_id[2] == 0:
        df_final.to_csv('temporary_saved_files2/' + str(df_plus_id[2]) + '.csv', index=False)
    else:
        df_final.to_csv('temporary_saved_files2/' + str(df_plus_id[2]) + '.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

and here's the code that calls generate function:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

number_of_CPU = "Max"
if  type(number_of_CPU) == int and number_of_CPU < mp.cpu_count() and number_of_CPU > 0 :
    processes = number_of_CPU
else:
    processes = mp.cpu_count()

# if number of processess > number of lines in df, make processses= number of lines.
if processes > df.shape[0]:
    processes = df.shape[0]
print('Generating the new training data using %s'%str(processes)+ ' processes.')
# Determine chunk size, which is the number of lines per processes
list_of_dfs = []
chunk_size = int(math.ceil(df.shape[0] / processes))
start = 0
end = chunk_size

# Divide the dataframe into chunks
for i in range(processes):

    if start >= df.shape[0]:
                break
    list_of_dfs.append([df.iloc[start:end, :],df_final.iloc[start:end, :],i])
    start = end
    end = end + chunk_size


processes = len(list_of_dfs)
# Make temporary directory for intermediate results
os.mkdir('temporary_saved_files2')

with mp.Pool(processes) as pool:  # or whatever your hardware can support
    pool.map(generate, list_of_dfs)
os.popen('cat temporary_saved_files2/*.csv  >' + 'trial').read()
os.popen('rm -r temporary_saved_files2').read()
```

Any idea why is this?